# How to spawn a repeating task and await its first execution?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

Re-building `setInterval` in JS:

```rust
pub async fn set_interval<T, F>(interval: Duration, do_something: T)
where
    T: (Fn() -> F) + Send + Sync + 'static,
    F: Future + Send,
{
    let forever = task::spawn(async move {
        let mut interval = time::interval(interval);

        loop {
            interval.tick().await;
            do_something().await;
        }
    });

    forever.await;
}
```

This works, but I want it to be `.await`able until the first execution ends.

I.e. Instead of doing:

```rust
do_something().await
set_interval(Duration::from_secs(1), do_something)
```

I want to:

```rust
set_interval(Duration::from_secs(1), do_something).await
```

Note that this is different behaviour from above in that it runs the `do_something` task immediately, but it's intended.

My solution:

```rust
pub async fn set_interval<T, F>(interval: Duration, do_something: T)
where
    T: (Fn() -> F) + Send + Sync + 'static,
    F: Future + Send,
{
    do_something().await;
    
    task::spawn(async move {
        let forever = task::spawn(async move {
            let mut interval = time::interval(interval);

            loop {
                interval.tick().await;
                do_something().await;
            }
        });

        forever.await;
    });
}
```

This works, but I have some doubts

1. Is it a waste of resources to `task::spawn` twice here? Any way it can be done only once?
2. Is it a mistake to discard the outer `task::spawn` as soon as the function ends? Will it keep getting run indefinitely, even though it's not tracked anymore, just fired and forgotten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your two questions:

1. Don't worry about spawning a task too many: On your average hardware, you should be able to spawn a few 100,000 of them per second. It is unnecessary in this case, though, because:
2. Tasks get "detached" if they are dropped, so the futures inside them continue to be polled by your runtime. This also means that you don't need `forever.await`;

The following seems to work:

```
pub async fn set_interval<T, F>(interval: std::time::Duration, do_something: T)
where
    T: (Fn() -> F) + Send + Sync + 'static,
    F: std::future::Future + Send,
{
    // The interval time alignment is decided at construction time. 
    // For all calls to be evenly spaced, the interval must be constructed first.
    let mut interval = tokio::time::interval(interval);
    // The first tick happens without delay.
    // Whether to tick before the first do_something or after doesn't matter.
    interval.tick().await;
    
    do_something().await;
    
    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            interval.tick().await;
            do_something().await;
        }
    });
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9acd373cac76ec12b6dd5ee432108492)

Comment: thanks! Any reason why you moved `let mut interval` outside the task?

Comment: Right, I wanted to explain that. Post edited. Though maybe the [source](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.17.0/src/tokio/time/interval.rs.html#76) is easier to understand.

Comment: that's perfect!